# How to make data points equal to 0 appear on axis using ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am trying to make my data points that are equal to 0 appear on the x axis and avoid having data points cut by the axis.
I also want to keep my origin as it is (same 0 for both axis).

[Here is my graph:](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uSedR.jpg)

I used this to obtain the origin at 0 and to set the limits of my axis:

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40), expand = c(0, 0))+
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 30), expand = c(0, 0))
```

If I change the limit of y for

```
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(-1, 40))
```

it also changes the origin...

Here is all I my code in case you need it:

```
require(ggplot2)
myplot<-ggplot(data=NULL,aes(x = Length, y = Complete)) +
geom_point(data = C,shape=1, size=3)+
geom_point(data = T, size=3)+
scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0, 40), expand = c(0, 0))+
scale_x_continuous(limits = c(0, 30), expand = c(0, 0))+
xlab("Inflorescence Length (cm)")+
ylab("Successful Weevils")+
theme_bw() + 
theme(panel.border = element_blank())+
theme(panel.grid.major = element_blank())+
theme(panel.grid.minor = element_blank())+
theme(axis.text=element_text(size=12))+
theme(axis.title=element_text(size=14,face="bold"))+
theme(axis.line.x=element_line())+
theme(axis.line.y=element_line())+
theme(plot.margin = unit(c(1,1,1,1), "cm"))+
stat_smooth(data = C, method = lm, se=FALSE, color="grey")+
stat_smooth(data = T, method = lm, se=FALSE, color="black")
myplot
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to turn off clipping:

```
library(grid)
library(ggplot2)
df <- data.frame(x=1:1000, y=runif(1000))
p <- ggplot(df, aes(x,y)) + geom_point() + scale_y_continuous(limits = c(0,1), expand=c(0,0))
gt <- ggplot_gtable(ggplot_build(p))
gt$layout$clip[gt$layout$name=="panel"] <- "off"
grid.draw(gt)
```